# How to sort dictionary of sets by using length to sort them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Key Is a number and value of key is a set i want to sort them according to length of sets?

```
Ans={}
    for i in range(N):
        x=set(x for x in range(1,N+1))
        Ans[i+1]=x
```

In later stages of code this dictionary will have values of variable length and I want to sort them according to length of set as a value to key !

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve *the specific problem* you are asking about here? Your code does not inspect lengths nor sort in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the dictionary which is a `int->set` mapping, this piece of code should be enough

```
Ans = {item[0]:item[1] for item in sorted(Ans.items(), key= lambda x: len(x[1]))}
```

It converts the dictionary to a tuple sorted on values, and build the dictionary from it. There could be better ways, but this was something first came in mind.!

Comment: A dictionary is not an ordered collection. When you convert the tuples to a new dictionary it isn't guaranteed to stay sorted. You should leave it as tuples or used `OrderedDict`

Comment: @chuck2002 ``dict`` is officially sorted since Python3.7, and de-facto sorted since Python3.6.

Comment: Really? I thought just in small samples it was (like `set` sometimes) but isn't guaranteed. Cool to know

Comment: And I think I did not sort the dictionary!